# Remember me in Asp.Net Mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-4

I am new one to Asp.Net Mvc4 with Entity Framework. I am trying to implement Remember me task in Log in page. Here i am not using any model property for Remember me. I am just passing the value to Controller from Model. Please help me to set a cookie in the controller.Thanks in advance.

This is my Model Code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Login"))
                { 

                    <p class="mt5 mb20">Login to access your account.</p>*@
                    <div>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName, new { @class = "form-control uname", placeholder = "UserName" })

                    @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.UserPassword, new { @class = "form-control pword", placeholder = "Password" })



                    @Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password?","Forgotpassword","Login",new {@class="navbar-link"})
                    <span>Remember</span><input type="checkbox" name="remember"/>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="login">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                }
```

This is the way i am getting the value in Controller.
This is my Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(Tbl_Users user, FormCollection forms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using below code

```
 //create the authentication ticket
    var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
      1,
      userId,  //user id
      DateTime.Now,
      DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2000),  // expiry in minutes
      rememberMe,  //true to remember if it is checked
      "", //roles 
      "/"
    );

    //encrypt the ticket and add it to a cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,   FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: I used this same code but it is showing error. Error message is: FormsAuthenticationTicket does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments.